# How to link to debug versions of binary libs

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, dynamic-linking

If I pass a lib name with **-l** option, then GCC will link to the best lib from /usr/lib. I think the dynamic version is chosen over the static version when both are present.

But there are also debug versions of the same lib. Debug versions are supposed to be compiled with optimisations off and extra runtime checks on. I checked it with the package manager (Synaptic on Ubuntu) that dbg versions are indeed installed on my computer, but not entirely sure where are those libs and how to link to them.

Any hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are aware of the name of the debug library, you can directly use it in compilation instead of going with -l option. For example :

```
gcc -o <output_file> *.c <libdebug_file>.so
```

Comment: Looks like knowing the lib names is the only way to avoid GCC's  default choice.

Answer (score 0):

how about moving those libraries to a different path rather than standard ones and then compile using  g++ with the `-l` (library-name option)

Comment: Don't want to move system libs. I don't know which libs to move too.

Comment: bad idea. this would make all the apps on the system that use those libraries switch to the debug ones. don't do that.